# Joomla 2.5 (3.x) extension manager not finding update of extensions

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have an issue with Joomla 2.5 extensions updates.

I've released a new version for a plugin made by myself and installed into my site. I have made the xml update server but inclusive other extensions that has a lot of updates aren't detected.

What could be the issue for this?

Comment: Please show the code for your update.xml file and the extension xml file

Comment: It has no science. I followed the instruction in [Joomla Develop Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server) but it doesn't work. and checked another examples from downloaded plugins has the same setting and the worked. As I saidin my question, Joomla is not detecting only my extension updates, nor all extensions updates. gets only joomla core prior updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good, 1 year later I could see the issue (for my extensions): on update server xml the tag *element* had a typo (minimum typo) and Joomla update manager were not able to find the updates to my extension.

the value for element tag had a *plugin_name* value (look at the underscore) but plugin is *pluginname*

for third party extensions, was a Joomla bug and I update the site to the current Joomla version.

Answer (score 0):

I previously found there was an issue with the version numbers: I had to use a 4-level version number ( 3.0.0.1 ) to get the automatic update to work. You could try that...

Comment: Thanks. currently I'm now in Joomla 3.x and the problem remains.

Do you mean in _<extension version="3.2" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">_ ?

replacing version="3.2" to version="3.0.0.1"?

Comment: No, I believe it's the other number, the actual version number of your plugin.

Comment: Sorry, it really sounds like it doesn't make sense, but it really did solve my troubles...

Comment: I will try with my extension versioning number although I don't mind it works. Thank you.